# CSS Menu Centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is probably something really obvious I'm missing but I can't seem to center this template menu I found. By center I mean center aligned within the screen. It's normally margin: 0px auto; and display: block; but I've had no luck.

Please see the jsfiddle link. If it doesn't display properly, drag the 'Results' tab to the left.

Many thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/dtb08ng1/

```
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">.com</a></li>
         <li><a href="">8</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Lion</a></li>
         <li><a href="">News</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
   <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is is OK if give you complete CSS solution. No Jquery.

Comment: Hi Divy,

Yes sure, I can't imagine that the Jquery side of it needs to be changed. It must be something in the CSS.

Do you need me to post the CSS here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
 #cssmenu {
      width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
display:inline-block
}
```

Hope this will help you:

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
        $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
          var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
          if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
            mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
          }
          else {
            mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
            if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
              mainmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
          }
        });

        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

        multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
            }
            else {
              $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
            }
          });
        };

        if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
        else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    format: "multitoggle"
  });

  $("#cssmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

var foundActive = false, activeElement, linePosition = 0, menuLine = $("#cssmenu #menu-line"), lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

$("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    activeElement = $(this);
    foundActive = true;
  }
});

if (foundActive === false) {
  activeElement = $("#cssmenu > ul > li").first();
}

defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

$("#cssmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
  activeElement = $(this);
  lineWidth = activeElement.width();
  linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
  menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
  menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
}, 
function() {
  menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
  menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
});

});


});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/*------------------ CSS Menu ------------------*/
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none; 
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #000000;
}
#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #71b51e;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #71b51e;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #71b51e;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #71b51e;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
 margin : 0px auto;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li,
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-line {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
    top: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
#cssmenu {
   
      width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">.com</a></li>
         <li><a href="">8</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Lion</a></li>
   <li><a href="">News</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
   <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi Sergey,

It centered nicely, but it got rid of the green slider that follows the mouse hover. Is there a way of keeping this at the same time?

Many thanks

Comment: hm.. code editor in stackoverflow cut some styles please check updates here: https://jsfiddle.net/dtb08ng1/2/

Comment: Wow that is awesome, thank you. Is it possible not to center the drop-down menu though?

So when hovering over 'Products' the drop-down menu has its text displayed in the center, is there a simple way to align it to the left.

Thanks again!

Comment: You can just add style like it: #cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li { text-align:left}  and text in your dropdown menu will be left-aligned

Answer (score 2):

Just change in css file below code:

**CSS**

```
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #fff;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hi DotNet,

Thanks for your help.

That just seemed to center the submenu text. I was looking to center the entire menu. Or am I mis-reading you there.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the `div#cssmenu` element in a `div#container`. That way you can make the menu `display: inline-block;` and use `text-align: center;` on the container `div`.

See updated JSfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/dtb08ng1/2/.

#### Update

The new CSS I added to get this to work is as follows:

```
#container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
#cssmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  …
}
```

The only HTML change I made was to wrap the `div#cssmenu` as follows:

```
…
<div id="container">
  <div id="cssmenu">
  …
  </div>
</div>
…
```

Comment: Hi Robin,

That looks great, could you highlight the code that you changed so I can understand what you did? Also is there a way for the sub-menu text not to be center aligned?

Many thanks

Comment: See updated code. Also, giving `#cssmenu` the property `text-align: left;` will prevent the centering of the submenu items.

Answer (score 0):

Most **Simple Pure CSS Menu**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li {
  font: 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  color: #71b51e;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 57px;
  width: 140px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li {
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  height: 25px;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #111;
  color: #71b51e;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>PRODUCTS</li>
  <li>
    EVENTS
    <ul>
      <li>.com</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>Lion</li>
      <li>News</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>ABOUT US</li>
</ul>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/342yjs8a/)